# Select another post in a post meta like a parent page is selected while editing a page

Tags: posts, post-meta, post-editor

I have a series of 'post's like 'Title 01', 'Title 02', 'Title 03', ... and so on. When editing a 'post', I want to add a previous and a next post (of the series) ids as the post meta. I have added the meta box with two `<select>`s and populate them (with posts excluding the editing post by `get_posts()`) and save the data.

But my query is, can I insert an input like it is offered when I choose a 'page' parent, where it automatically searches the 'page' list?

Thanks in advance...

Note:

1. I do not want to make posts hierarchical.
2. There may be intermittent posts within two consecutive series articles. So normal 'next' and 'previous' posts wont work.
3. I can apply `select2` to the `<select>` list. This is definitely a solution, but not what I am looking for.
4. A cocktail of `select2` with ajax will serve the purpose, but is there anything easier? Any such WordPress oriented function or so?

Comment: Are you adding this to the block editor or the classic editor?

Comment: block editor using WP 5.7.2